# understanding this scala code

Tags: c++, scala

I am trying to convert some Scala code to C++ and this is my first time having any exposure to Scala and I am having trouble with a certain bit of code. So, I have a base class as follows:

```
sealed abstract class FactorNode(factor: Factor) extends Node {
    private var _factor: Factor = factor
    def factorMarginal(): Factor
}
```

Now I have a derived class as follows:

```
case class SingleFactorNode(factor: SingleFactor, gate: FactorGate) extends FactorNode(factor) {
    def factorMarginal(): Factor = {
    val inMsg = gate.getEndGate().getMessage()
    val factorMarginal = factor * inMsg
    factorMarginal
    }
}
```

Couple of questions: 1: The `factorMarginal()` method in the base class. It seems to have no body and returns nothing. How does this work? Is it completely superfluous the way it stands?

2: Second the `factorMarginal()` method in the derived class. Is that over riding the base factorMarginal method. Also, the last line in this method called itself (without any parenthesis) and I am confused as to what that does. Is it called the base class factorMarginal or implementing some sort of recursion?

Comment: It' probably a bad idea to translate Scala code to C++. Can't you just re-implement the algorithm in C++? The samples you provide look like there should exist a research paper describing this algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `factorMarginal` method in the base class is abstract. In C++ you would make it pure virtual:

```
virtual Factor factorMarginal() = 0;
```

Yes, the `factorMarginal` method in the derived class overrides the one in the base class. In C++ you would write it as follows:

```
virtual Factor factorMarginal() override {
    auto const inMsg = gate.getEndGate().getMessage();
    return factor * inMsg;
}
```

The last line doesn’t call the method itself, but it returns the local variable with the same name.

Be sure to make the methods `const` in C++ if this makes sense.

Note that there is no C++ equivalent for Scala’s `sealed`.

Comment: I was going to do that but it asks me to wait 10 minutes as I am a n00b! :)